# How do I center images inside a list?

Tags: html, css, image, list, alignment

How do I align a list of images to be centered? I have them 25 pixels apart from each other. They are displaying inline. Now I want to center them on the page. Right now they are shifted left.

HTML

```
<div class="thumbnail-photos">
  <ul>
      <li><img src="images2.jpg height="100" width="100" /></li>
      <li><img src="images2.jpg height="100" width="100" /></li>
      <li><img src="images2.jpg height="100" width="100" /></li>
      <li><img src="images2.jpg height="100" width="100" /></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.thumbnail-photos ul li {
    display: inline;
    margin: 25px;
}
```

I tried `text-align: center;` in `.thumbnail-photos ul li` and `.thumbnail-photos ul li img`

Comment: You can try `.thumbnail-photos { margin: 0 auto;}`

Comment: can you create a fiddle. It would be much easier to debug jsfiddle.net

Comment: and don't forget to select an answer when done :)

Comment: @AnkurAggarwal here is a fiddle i created http://jsfiddle.net/pzQ5S/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to center on page - the trick is to specify a width to the wrapper container:

```
.thumbnail-photos {
    width: 900px; /* any width you want */
    margin: 0 auto;     
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/blurfus/6cJ2a/1/)**

Comment: yes that was in the description part, i didn't noticed,thanks anyway +1

Comment: That's the result I'm looking for. Thanks.

Comment: @blurfus here is the section of my project http://jsfiddle.net/JonaTheApprentice/U5hwL/

Comment: you can adjust the width of the container as you see fit; if you want only four images, you can set the `width: 700px;` and it will center it in the page.  This is because it is centering the container with respect to the document (and the images with respect to the container)

Answer (score 1):

Please update the following css.

```
.thumbnail-photos ul li {
display: inline-block;
margin: 25px;
width:120px;/*---any specific width to check----*/
}
.thumbnail-photos ul li img {
display:block;
margin:0 auto;
}
```